# How can I change a variable in a javascript array without the other variables changes being declared?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I have a randomized quiz and, to check the answer, I used a variable. However, it just skips to the end and declares the variable to be "11".

```
aVocab[intCat]= new Array();
aVocab[intCat][0]="FIRST"
aVocab[intCat][1] = new Array()
aVocab[intCat][1][intIncr++]="a"; var celebrity = 1
aVocab[intCat][1][intIncr++]="b"; var celebrity = 2
aVocab[intCat][1][intIncr++]="c"; var celebrity = 3
aVocab[intCat][1][intIncr++]="d"; var celebrity = 4
aVocab[intCat][1][intIncr++]="e"; var celebrity = 5
aVocab[intCat][1][intIncr++]="f"; var celebrity = 6
aVocab[intCat][1][intIncr++]="g"; var celebrity = 7
aVocab[intCat][1][intIncr++]="h"; var celebrity = 8
aVocab[intCat][1][intIncr++]="i"; var celebrity = 9
aVocab[intCat][1][intIncr++]="j"; var celebrity = 10
aVocab[intCat][1][intIncr++]="k"; var celebrity = 11
```

The alert code that checks it is:

```
function display_alert()
  {
if (celebrity===1)
  {
  alert("1")
  }
else if (celebrity===2)
  {
  alert("2")
  }
else if (celebrity===3)
  {
  alert("3")
  }
else if (celebrity===4)
  {
  alert("4")
  }
else if (celebrity===5)
  {
  alert("5")
  }
else if (celebrity===6)
  {
  alert("6")
  }
else if (celebrity===7)
  {
  alert("7")
  }
else if (celebrity===8)
  {
  alert("8")
  }
else if (celebrity===9)
  {
  alert("9")
  }
else if (celebrity===10)
  {
  alert("10")
  }
else if (celebrity===11)
  {
  alert("11")
  }
else
  {
  alert("This is for debugging")
  }
  }
```

I think this happens because of the multiple variable declares but I don't know how to escape them. To clear up confusion, I'm making a celebrity quiz for a school project and wanted to define each array with it's own value.

Comment: Try putting an if statement around each of the `var celebrity = n` statements, otherwise all of them will run and only the last one will have an effect. The celebrity variable is not currently part of the array, you are simply re-declaring it 11 times.

Comment: Tip: use a switch statement

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `celebrity`? As you have it you redefine it over and over, leaving it with a value of 11, so your function is doing precisely what one would expect. What is supposed to happen?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for objects inside your array? Something like `aVocab[intCat][1][intIncr++] = { key: 'a', celebrity: 1 }`?

Comment: Please, use a simple `function display_alert() { alert(celebrity); }` (and maybe check for type, range, and integrality if you need the "debugging alert")

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a comment. In your code you have:

```
aVocab[intCat]= new Array();
aVocab[intCat][0]="FIRST"
aVocab[intCat][1] = new Array()
aVocab[intCat][1][intIncr++]="a"; var celebrity = 1
aVocab[intCat][1][intIncr++]="b"; var celebrity = 2
...
aVocab[intCat][1][intIncr++]="k"; var celebrity = 11
```

which declares *celebrity* multiple times and assigns a new value each time.  The multiple declaration isn't harmful, just redundant. At the end of the code, *celebrity* will have the last assigned value, which is `11`.

> I think this happens because of the multiple variable declares but I don't know how to escape them

Not multiple declarations, but multiple assignments.

You haven't explained what *aVocab* is, or *intCat*, nor have you indicated how *intIncr* is initialised. Anyhow, maybe bfavaretto's comment is on the money and you want some kind of array of objects.

Comment: The quiz is supposed to randomize what question you receive and display it but I want the alert box to show the answer so I assigned the variable 11 times, one for each question. As for your question, aVocab, intCat, and intIncr are all just a part of the script that randomizes the array results, but that works fine.